# after push_back cin doesnt work

Tags: c++

I have a problem with this code:

```
int main()
{
    int x, sum = 0, how_many;
    vector<int> v;

    cout << "Write few numbers (write a letter if u want to end)\n";

    while (cin >> x)
    {
        v.push_back(x);
    }

    cout << "How many of those first numbers do u want to sum up?" << endl;
    cin >> how_many;

    for (int i = 0; i < how_many; ++i)
    {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    cout << "The sum of them is " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that console doesn't let me even write sth into `how_many` and error occurs. When I put lines 6 and 7 before `cout << "Write few..."` it all works perfectly. Can someone tell me why is that happening?

Answer (score 6):

The loop ends when `cin` fails to convert the input into an integer, which leaves `cin` in a bad state. It also still contains final line of input. Any further input will fail, unless you clear the bad state:

```
cin.clear();    // clear the error state
cin.ignore(-1); // ignore any input still in the stream
```

(If you like verbosity, you could specify `std::numeric_limits<std::stream_size>::max()`, rather than relying on the conversion of `-1` to the maximum value of an unsigned type).

Answer (score 3):

You need to clear the `cin` error state because you ended the `int vector` read operation by an error.

```
cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```